# Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to find the id from an array. But when I run it Type Error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')`. I'm doing this watching a tutorial. It works fine. but in my code, it doesn't work. BTW I'm new to react

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data';


function ProductScreen(props) {
  const product = data.products.find(x=>x._id===props.match.params.id);
    return <div>
       <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    </div>
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Are you using a routing library?  could you double-check you've provided providers?

Comment: Yes I'm using react router dom

Comment: Could you please show where you use the ProductScreen component?

Comment: import React from "react";
import HomeScreen  from './HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './ProductScreen';
import { Routes ,Route } from "react-router-dom";


function Main(){
   return (
    <main className="main">
    <div className="content">
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />}/>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} element={<HomeScreen />}/> 
  </Routes>
    </div>
</main>
   )
}

export default Main;

Comment: @Khalid please add that to the question